# Criteria on domain which does not have reference of another domain

Tags: grails, grails-orm, createcriteria

I have domain like

```
class Book {
    Author author
    String title
}
```

and another

```
class ListingTracking {
    Book book
    String oldVal
    String newVal
    Date modDate
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

and now I need all those listingTacking which have a list of book ids but my criteria is on Book domain and I can not change association.

I tried

```
   def books= Book.createCriteria().list {

    'in'("id", [7,2,3,6].collect {it as Long} )
    createAlias("listingTracking","lt")
    projections{
        property("title")
    }
    'in'("lt.book.id",[7,2,3,6].collect {it as Long})

}
```

I know that I can't create createAlias of listingTracking in Book domain but I need something like that, Is this possible via criteria?.

Answer (score 0):

```
def listingTracking = ListingTracking.findAllByBookInList( Book.getAll([7,2,3,6]) )
```

Instead of Book.getAll you can use any finder you prefer on Books